# No data on AWS Kinesis after putRecords

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Disclaimer: This is the first time I am using AWS Kinesis, so I might be expecting something that is not correct.

I have a very simple AWS Lambda function that inserts data into Kinesis. The API response indicates that there were no errors, and no exceptions are thrown; Kinesis simply confirms that everything went fine. However, when I go to the AWS console and try to query the data, there is nothing there!

```
const records = [
  { partitionKey: '1', data: 'Record 1' },
  { partitionKey: '2', data: 'Record 2' },
  { partitionKey: '3', data: 'Record 3' },
]

const params = {
  Records: records.map((record) => ({
    Data: record.data,
    PartitionKey: record.partitionKey,
  })),
  StreamName: streamName,
}

const response = await kinesis.putRecords(params).promise()

const suscess = response.FailedRecordCount === 0
```

`suscess` is true.

So, I tried to retrieve the data using code within the same Lambda function. Right after inserting the data into Kinesis, I added the following code:

```
const params2 = {
  ShardIteratorType: 'LATEST',
  ShardId: 'shardId-000000000000',
  StreamName: streamName,
}

const response2 = await kinesis.getShardIterator(params2).promise()
const shardIterator = response2.ShardIterator

const records2 = await kinesis.getRecords({ ShardIterator: shardIterator! }).promise()
```

`records2` is an empty array.

To my surprise, no records were returned; the response was empty, and no useful information was retrieved. Additionally, no exceptions were thrown.

I checked the shardId, and it does exist.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong?

Why does AWS Kinesis indicate that it inserted the data, but nothing seems to be happening? In the AWS console, I can see activities in the put and get operations from the usage graphs.

Comment: Have you checked Kinesis metrics on CloudWatch to see if data was received by Kinesis?

Comment: @TofigHasanov, in CloudWatch, there is nothing, but I didn't have the option to select anything other than Kinesis itself. However, in the Kinesis interface, there is data, and it indicates that the percentage of put operations was 100% successful. Something seems very wrong.

Comment: `LATEST` gives you records that were received on/after the time you call `getShardIterator()`, but you wrote the records _before_ getting the iterator. Check the docs for the correct iterator type.

Comment: I have tried with other options and got the same result: nothing. I’m about to throw the towel and use Redis, for my case is a good fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have recently started using Kinesis Data Streams, I recommend reading the [architecture and terminology document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/key-concepts.html). It will give you insights into how data is internally streamed in the system.

According to AWS documentation:

> A Kinesis data stream is a set of shards. Each shard has a sequence of data records. Each data record has a sequence number that is assigned by Kinesis Data Streams.

Based on this definition, Kinesis data streams internally use shards to stream data. If you are using the *on-demand* capacity mode, it will initially allocate a minimum of 4 shards and increase the number of shards based on your application's throughput. However, if you create Kinesis Data Streams using the *Provisioned* mode, you must use a minimum of 2 shards. Therefore, Kinesis data streams always have more than one shard to handle data streaming.

Regarding the code you used on the consumer side, you explicitly hard-coded the shard ID value as `shardId-000000000000`, but you cannot be certain whether the data you published was sent to that particular shard ID. So, apart from checking the `FailedRecords` count on the publisher side, log the complete response of `putRecords` method, and it will show you which `shardId` is used to steam your data.

To simplify things, I used an AWS CLI command to publish the data, which you can easily interpret/convert to node.js to achieve the same result.

PutRecords Command:

```
aws kinesis put-records \
    --stream-name <ENTER_STREAM_NAME_HERE> \
    --records Data="Record 1",PartitionKey="1" Data="Record 2",PartitionKey="2" Data="Record 3",PartitionKey="3" --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out
```

PutRecords Response:

```
{
    "FailedRecordCount": 0,
    "Records": [
        {
            "SequenceNumber": "49643231014796346134140772956682328171122645057423802450",
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000005"
        },
        {
            "SequenceNumber": "49643231014796346134140772956683537096942259686598508626",
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000005"
        },
        {
            "SequenceNumber": "49643231014796346134140772956684746022761874315773214802",
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000005"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you observe the above response, when I executed the `put-records` command, the data was sent to `shardId-000000000005`.

Let's assume that, I haven't consumed any records earlier from this shard, so I'm going to use `TRIM_HORIZON` as `ShardIteratorType` to get the data pointer value.

GetShardIterator command:

```
aws kinesis get-shard-iterator \
    --stream-name <ENTER_STREAM_NAME_HERE> \
    --shard-id shardId-000000000005 \
    --shard-iterator-type TRIM_HORIZON
```

GetShardIterator Response:

```
{
    "ShardIterator": "AAAAAAAAAAH2b4HgeaV/7klnxSTYd3/T9YcQ2eKxjELpkEgXAy1k0hVidh05ZeIUdMBHo0SdJOjBq5HWwGG3dZPCKM8kTBYCWYLhv7OrC9PQo6qdRuhC8uY4LH6GEBenMgf7dzS1wD/oep8EKZvSblDYVCfcpoXT4NbWIt8D5mvx4ZlPssmyuRR92DM0ywU6PjTM8tgOoixD5kEDro/SANFc5ohKIiOHxWjUsfpgvMoJFIFtLpkgQQ=="
}
```

The above response contains the pointer record to read the oldest (untrimmed) data record from the shard: `shardId-000000000005`. Once we have the iterator value, we can use the `get-records` method to fetch records.

GetRecords command:

```
aws kinesis get-records \
    --shard-iterator AAAAAAAAAAH2b4HgeaV/7klnxSTYd3/T9YcQ2eKxjELpkEgXAy1k0hVidh05ZeIUdMBHo0SdJOjBq5HWwGG3dZPCKM8kTBYCWYLhv7OrC9PQo6qdRuhC8uY4LH6GEBenMgf7dzS1wD/oep8EKZvSblDYVCfcpoXT4NbWIt8D5mvx4ZlPssmyuRR92DM0ywU6PjTM8tgOoixD5kEDro/SANFc5ohKIiOHxWjUsfpgvMoJFIFtLpkgQQ==
```

GetRecords response:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "SequenceNumber": "49643231014796346134140772956682328171122645057423802450",
            "ApproximateArrivalTimestamp": "2023-08-02T22:15:34.035000+00:00",
            "Data": "UmVjb3JkIDE=",
            "PartitionKey": "1"
        },
        {
            "SequenceNumber": "49643231014796346134140772956683537096942259686598508626",
            "ApproximateArrivalTimestamp": "2023-08-02T22:15:34.038000+00:00",
            "Data": "UmVjb3JkIDI=",
            "PartitionKey": "2"
        },
        {
            "SequenceNumber": "49643231014796346134140772956684746022761874315773214802",
            "ApproximateArrivalTimestamp": "2023-08-02T22:15:34.038000+00:00",
            "Data": "UmVjb3JkIDM=",
            "PartitionKey": "3"
        }
    ],
    "NextShardIterator": "AAAAAAAAAAHIu30Hail1drAR8L9vok/zazMmRawSMqVACRymRKho+06rk6PHZ0G9JbYJLzIjUoo3UVT3XiqcfTL/QO6Dt1SJhY7p2P50V8Dhv2pkGavpNnh43114Mp4i3HAUSsYkwNRW8EJSIcJ/LZysNG1z0KLmbBp+Vau5UOj9mbZu4aU7H+97WqJkoHvK8/BC2AcMnVUlR03/xVHS8zy9fer8v6bRCjDgJMCU9CHyJamX5Douqg==",
    "MillisBehindLatest": 0
}
```

In your code, you used the `ShardIteratorType` value as `LATEST`, which creates a pointer after the last published record in the shard. So, if you use the `LATEST` iterator type, make sure you get the iterator value first before publishing the data. You can also consider using other iterator types, as described in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_GetShardIterator.html) document.

I presume that you have now identified the problems in your code, which could be in two places:

1. *ShardId* => The publisher might have used a different `shardId` than the value you specified in the code.
2. *ShardIteratorType* => Since you executed the consumer code after publishing the data, it will create a pointer after the recently published records. As a result, even if the publisher sent messages to `shardId-0000000000000`, you won't be able to retrieve the values that you published earlier.